# How to use aggregate functions in my criteria in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, aggregate-functions

I have table called `VoucherEntry`

These are my records,

```
ID    VoucherOnlineID    TransactionNumber    Store    Amount  
-------------------------------------------------------------
120    137                26                   1001     100
126    137                22                   2000     -56
128    137                30                   3000     -20
133    137                11                   2000     -5
```

Now I want to add 2 columns which is having **carry amount and Balance amount**. If the `VoucherEntry.Amount = 100` Then carry column should be 0, other wise it should display like below

**Expecting output**

```
ID    VoucherOnlineID    TransactionNumber    Store    Carry    Amount   Balance
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
120    137                26                   1001     0        100      100
126    137                22                   2000     100      -56      44
128    137                30                   3000     44       -20      24
133    137                11                   2000     24       -5       19
```

**Update**

> we can sort the record By `ID` column or `Date` column, after you sort the records will display in above order

Comment: please tag your dbms and explain your logic clearly.

Comment: How do you order your rows?

Comment: @Lamak by `ID or Date`, You can sort the table either by `ID or Date`, I will update now

Comment: `Lag(Amount) over (partition by VoucherOnlineID order by Date)` seems to be a useful function here if supported.

Comment: How is carry calculated for entries which don't have an amount of 100?

Comment: @XCVD that's why I said, `if the amount is = 100 then carry is 0 or ' '`, Because that will be starting point.

Comment: But the data you provided does not make sense in that case. If the amount is -20, how do you calculate the balance as 24 and the carry as 44? Those values would need to be provided or your math isn't adding up! Or are you summing previous lines? That is the part that is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two variations of a *Cumulative Sum*:

```
SELECT 
   VoucherOnlineID
  ,TransactionNumber
  ,Store
  ,Coalesce(Sum(Amount) -- Cumulative Sum of previous rows
            Over (PARTITION BY VoucherOnlineID 
                  ORDER BY DATE -- or whatever determines correct order
                  ROWS BETWEEN Unbounded Preceding AND 1 Preceding), 0) AS Carry
  ,Amount
  ,Sum(Amount) -- Cumulative Sum including current row
   Over (PARTITION BY VoucherOnlineID 
         ORDER BY DATE -- or whatever determines correct order
         ROWS Unbounded Preceding) AS Balance
FROM VoucherEntry
```

Comment: please wait let me check

Comment: @dneoth MR.Genius, I accept your answer. I don't want to do copy and paste. Can you give me more info about your partition please?. Thanks

Comment: @mohamedfaiz: `PARTITION BY` is similar to `GROUP BY` it resets the calculation wherever the voucher id changes.

Answer (score 0):

sql Server 2008 and below

```
declare @t table(ID int,VoucherOnlineID int,TransactionNumber int,Store int,Amount int)  
insert into  @t  VALUES
(120,137,26,1001,100)
,(126,137,22,2000,-56)
,(128,137,30,3000,-20)
,(133,137,11,2000,-5 )

select *
,isnull((Select sum(Amount) from @t t1 
where t1.VoucherOnlineID=t.VoucherOnlineID 
and t1.id<t.id  ) ,0)Carry    
,isnull((Select sum(Amount) from @t t1 
where t1.VoucherOnlineID=t.VoucherOnlineID 
and t1.id<=t.id  ) ,0)Balance
from  @t t
```